# Remove Payment Due for Sales order

Tags: sales-order, payment

How do we remove additional payment due on Magento if the customer paid outside of Magento?

The case is the customer bought a product online and paid but changed his order and sent an additional payment outside Magento.

After editing the Magento order there was an amount due.

How do we remove this?

Answer (score 1):

If sales order has been changed then previous order must be cancelled out by Magento.

In both of the Magento 1 and Magento 2 versions, credit memo maybe worked.

Magento 1 - https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/order-processing/credit-memo-create.html

Magento 2 - https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/credit-memos.html

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. The order was not yet shipped so we are still able to edit it. But since the payment was captured outside Magento their is still a due amount on the order

Comment: Ah.. create a offline payment method - 'outside payment received' then generate credit memo with payment also 'refund outside'. if you have online payment then you can also generate refund online.

Comment: I saw that there is a Capture Offline feature in Magento 2. Is there such feature in Magento 1?